# Flutter: NavigationRail and routes - how to keep the rail when routing?

Tags: flutter, routes

I'm coding a small web app with Flutter at the moment. I have a NavigationRail for the main screens but need routing between them. One is a "search" screen where i can search for events. I want to list there all available events with a detail button. If it is pressed I'd like to route to another NavgiationRail entry "event" screen. Now I could route to the screen but I'd loose the NavigationRail. So any hints how to achieve this?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: BackendRouteConfig.routes,
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationRail(
            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.all,
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                label: Text('Search'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.smartphone_outlined),
                label: Text('Event'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const VerticalDivider(thickness: 1, width: 1),
          Expanded(
            child: _buildContent(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildContent() {
    switch (_selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return const HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return const CreatorScreen();
      case 2:
        return const EventScreen();
      default:
        return const HomeScreen();
    }
  }
}
```